# Ant java task cannot find class

Tags: ant

I am using ant 1.9.6 on windows7. I get an error in the java run task, which says that Could not find class. It seems that my classpath is not set properly. Can anyone help me in getting the classpath set properly.
Below is my build.xml

```
<project name="MyTask" basedir=".">


<property name="proj.dir" value="C:\Zeeshan\testing-buildautomation\IntLeaveModuleApp"/>
<property name="db.user" value="msd_test"/>
<property name="db.pwd" value="msd_testpwd"/>


<path id="java">

    <fileset dir="./tmp">
        <include name="*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="buildAppScopeJDBCEAR">
    <mkdir dir="src"/>
    <mkdir dir="./src/META-INF"/>
    <copy file="../commonfiles/weblogic-application.xml" todir="./src/META-INF"/>
    <copy file="../commonfiles/weblogic-jdbc.xml" todir="./src/META-INF"/>
    <java classname="tmp.UpdateXML" >
        <classpath refid="java" /> 

        <!--<arg value="${db.user}" />
        <arg value="${db.pwd}" /> -->
    </java>

</target>

   </project>
```

My folder structure is above
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `build.xml` is in the same directory as your class. When you invoke ant, the basedir is set to wherever this file is located.

You may want to move `build.xml` up to `IntLeaveModuleApp`.

I also think that `proj.dir` is redundant since you can refer to `${basedir}` instead.

Comment: Apologies. Actually my build.xml is in the basedir location, which is C:\Zeeshan\testing-buildautomation\IntLeaveModuleApp.